# "remove type arguments" in code-cleanup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I recently switched a project from java 1.6 to 1.7. Now I'm getting these "Redundant specification of type arguments xxx"-warnings from Eclipse. Since I'm too lazy to remove these warnings by hand I wanted this be done by a code cleanup. Eclipse offers me the quickfix "remove type arguments". I couldn't find anything in the code-cleanup menu.

Any hints how to achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an open bug (and a quite valid requirement as needlessly (and manually) correcting 1000s of warnings is not an option).

You can vote for it [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351956).